# Counting words in text (in R): Results unreadable

Tags: r, dataframe, text-mining, word-frequency, qdap

I'm counting words in a given text using `R` libraries `tm` and `qdap`. When my vector (`words`) has only a few words, everything looks fine:

```
library(tm)
library(qdap)
text <- "activat affect affected affecting affects aggravat allow attribut based basis
bc because bosses caus change changed changes changing compel compliance"
text <- Corpus(VectorSource(text))
words <- c("activat", "affect", "affected")

# Using termco to search for the words in the text
apply_as_df(text, termco, match.list=words)

# Results:
#      docs    word.count    activat    affect    affected
# 1   doc 1            20   1(5.00%) 4(20.00%)    1(5.00%)
```

But when my vector (`words`) has too many words the results get garbled and unreadable:

```
words <- c("activat", "affect", "affected", "affecting", "affects", "aggravat", "allow",
           "attribut", "based", "basis", "bc", "because", "bosses", "caus", "change",
           "changed", "changes", "changing", "compel", "compliance")

# Using termco to search for the words in the text
apply_as_df(text, termco, match.list=words)

# Results:
#     docs word.count  activat    affect affected affecting  affects aggravat    allow
# attribut    based    basis       bc  because   bosses      caus    change  changed
#  changes changing   compel compliance
# 1  doc 1         20 1(5.00%) 4(20.00%) 1(5.00%)  1(5.00%) 1(5.00%) 1(5.00%) 1(5.00%)
# 1(5.00%) 1(5.00%) 1(5.00%) 1(5.00%) 1(5.00%) 1(5.00%) 2(10.00%) 3(15.00%) 1(5.00%)
# 1(5.00%) 1(5.00%) 1(5.00%)   1(5.00%)
```

---

**How can I have the results display in a dataframe/matrix so I can read them more easily?**

---

I tried using `termco2mat` (`qdap` library) which supposedly "returns a matrix of term counts" (https://trinker.github.io/qdap/termco.html) like so (please see below), but I'm getting an error:

```
apply_as_df(text, termco2mat, match.list=words)

# Results:
# Error in qdapfun(text.var = text, ...) : 
#   unused arguments (text.var = text, match.list = c("activat", "affect", "affected",
# "affecting", "affects", "aggravat", "allow", "attribut", "based", "basis", "bc",
# "because", "bosses", "caus", "change", "changed", "changes", "changing", "compel",
# "compliance"))
```

Or:

```
termco2mat(apply_as_df(text, termco, match.list=words))

# Results:
# Error in `rownames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = "doc 1") : 
#   attempt to set 'rownames' on an object with no dimensions
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution without qdap:

```
library(tm)
text1 <- "activat affect affected affecting affects aggravat allow attribut"
text2 <- "based basis bc because bosses caus change changed changes changing compel compliance"
text <- Corpus(VectorSource(c(text1, text2)))
words <- c("activat", "affect", "affected")

dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(text)
data.frame(cnt = colSums(as.matrix(dtm[ , words])))
```

Output

```
         cnt
activat    1
affect     1
affected   1
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do but `scores` `counts` are how to extract the objects from the list.  Maybe you want to `t` transpose the output?

```
apply_as_df(text, termco, match.list=words) %>%
    counts() %>%
    t()

## docs       "doc 1"
## word.count "20"   
## activat    "1"    
## affect     "4"    
## affected   "1"    
## affecting  "1"    
## affects    "1"    
## aggravat   "1"    
## allow      "1"    
## attribut   "1"    
## based      "1"    
## basis      "1"    
## bc         "1"    
## because    "1"    
## bosses     "1"    
## caus       "2"    
## change     "3"    
## changed    "1"    
## changes    "1"    
## changing   "1"    
## compel     "1"    
## compliance "1"
```